# Системное меню и фон текста Label

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, borland

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, с 2-мя вопросами:

1. Вверху справа окна программы - 3 значка: свернуть закрыть, и на весь экран:
   как значку Свернуть задать свои свойства, а развернуть на весь экран убрать?
2. Как тексту Label убрать задний фон (сделать прозрачным) он у меня на картинке, и фон все портит...

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Экспериментируй в свойствах формы с BorderIcons True/False

2: У Label есть свойство Transparent установи True и будет тебе счастье.